# Boot takes me to the Grub command line

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub

After adding another disk drive to my Arch Linux system, upon booting, I land directly at the Grub command line (not the Grub rescue prompt). Entering the following by hand boots up Linux:

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/grub
set root=(hd0,1)
insmod normal
insmod linux
normal
```

I've run `grub-mkconfig` and rebooted, but nothing changes. Is there some entry I need to make in `/etc/default/grub` or some other configuration file?

Comment: `grub-mkconfig` doesn't do what you think it does. This command only prints the configuration file to STDOUT, but doesn't actually update it. You can use the `-o` flag with mkconfig like so: `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` but the proper command to use these days is just `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Apparently Arch Linux doesn't have `update-grub`.